# Sending structured logs through proxy

Tags: proxy, firewall, serilog, seq, structured-data

I have a .NET application that runs on Windows and am trying to send the application logs/structured logs (Serilog) through a proxy to a log server. The Windows machine doesn't have access to the Internet, so I was thinking that I could setup a Proxy(Squid) to forward logs to the Serilog log server (in AWS).

A web browser on the Windows machine can access the log servers' webpage/dashboard, however, the application itself isn't able to send logs through the Squid proxy server.

Questions:

1. Is a Proxy server the correct tool to use in this scenario?
2. Just because a web browser on the Windows machine (configured to use the Proxy), can access the log servers' URL, should that mean my application which is streaming serilog structured data, be able to send logs to this server?
3. Should I be routing my serilog data through the Proxy server, or should I be using a reverse proxy instead?

Here is how the serilog data is expected to travel:

Client application -->> Proxy Server -->> Corporate Domain Firewall -->> AWS

Comment: Some follow-up questions that might help someone better placed to answer: what sink are you using? What log server? I would expect that the log server is the best context in which to get guidance - Serilog is only different/relevant until the point where the LogEvent is captured and ready to put in a file / send to a server via the Sink

Comment: I'm using the Serilog.Sinks.Seq sink. The more I look into this, it seems that proxy's are best suited for Web Browser traffic vs Application traffic. [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/766809/windows-send-all-traffic-via-my-own-proxy-server). This post seems to imply a firewall to route/redirect traffic may be the better option here. Can anyone confirm that using a firewall vs proxy best suited for this scenario?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.